# Nested method invocation

Tags: java, android

I need to call a similar function like the below one in java through reflection:

```
MyPrivateClass.getDefault("test").hitCurrentSetting(true);
```

I thought that I can implement this like this but it's not working and throw me not cast exception:

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.xyz.MyPrivateClass"), instance = null;

    instance = (Class<?>) c.getMethod("getDefault", String.class).invoke(null, "test");

    Method method = instance.getMethod("hitCurrentSetting", boolean.class);
    method.invoke(null, true);
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: How's your class look like?

Comment: There is usually a better way to do something than reflection.  I would suggest posting a more complete code sample and asking for suggestions on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Class<?> firstClass = Class.forName("com.xyz.MyPrivateClass");
Object firstCallResult = firstClass.getMethod("getDefault", String.class).invoke(null, "test");

Class<?> secondClass = firstCallResult.getClass();
Object secondCallResult = secondClass.getMethod("hitCurrentSetting", boolean.class).invoke(firstCallResult, true);
```